# Detecting parts of text in foreign languages (Rstudio)

Tags: text, filtering, tidytext

My dataset contains a lot of texts. Texts that were written entirely in foreign languages are dropped. Now, all the texts are written in English, but some have translations in them, e.g. someone that is bilingual that, besides the English text, has translated the english text underneath the English text in a non-English text. I want to filter out those parts of the texts.

The texts are all within a single variable. I have tried to unnest these texts (using tidytext's unnest_tokens function) and using the textcat package to detect the language of the unnested words, but this gives me the most discrepant languages, ranging from French to Slovenian, despite the corresponding words being English.

The code I used for this unnesting and detecting is as follows (I created a sample for the sake of performance):

```
text_unnesting_tokens <- MyDF %>% tidytext::unnest_tokens(word, text) 
sample <- text_unnesting_tokens[sample(nrow(text_unnesting_tokens), 5000), ]
sample$language <- textcat(sample$word, p = textcat::TC_char_profiles)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `textcat::textcat()` you should do that **before** tokenization, because it is based on whole pieces of text taken together, not on individual tokens. First use `textcat()` to identify languages and **then** tokenize:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(textcat)
library(hcandersenr)

fir_tree <- hca_fairytales() %>%
  filter(book == "The fir tree") 

## how many lines per language?
fir_tree %>%
  count(language)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   language     n
#>   <chr>    <int>
#> 1 Danish     227
#> 2 English    253
#> 3 French     227
#> 4 German     262
#> 5 Spanish    261

## how many lines per detected language?
fir_tree %>%
  mutate(detected_lang = textcat(text)) %>%
  count(detected_lang, sort = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 30 x 2
#>    detected_lang      n
#>    <chr>          <int>
#>  1 german           257
#>  2 spanish          238
#>  3 french           215
#>  4 english          181
#>  5 danish           138
#>  6 norwegian         80
#>  7 scots             60
#>  8 portuguese         7
#>  9 swedish            6
#> 10 middle_frisian     5
#> # … with 20 more rows

## now detect language + tokenize
fir_tree %>%
  mutate(detected_lang = textcat(text)) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text)
#> # A tibble: 14,850 x 4
#>    book         language detected_lang word    
#>    <chr>        <chr>    <chr>         <chr>   
#>  1 The fir tree Danish   danish        ude     
#>  2 The fir tree Danish   danish        i       
#>  3 The fir tree Danish   danish        skoven  
#>  4 The fir tree Danish   danish        stod    
#>  5 The fir tree Danish   danish        der     
#>  6 The fir tree Danish   danish        sådant  
#>  7 The fir tree Danish   danish        et      
#>  8 The fir tree Danish   danish        nydeligt
#>  9 The fir tree Danish   danish        grantræ 
#> 10 The fir tree Danish   danish        det     
#> # … with 14,840 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for you reply! However, this would give me the language of the majority of the within-cell text, right? What if, say, 60% is English and 40% is e.g. Spanish? Textcat will then determine it is an English written text. I need to remove this 40% from the dataset.

Comment: Ah wow, so your _documents_ are a mix of languages? You might consider some ngram tokenization, then language detection. I would recommend **not** trying language detection on single words.

Comment: That worked! FYI, I unnested the texts into sentences, determined the language, removed cases (sentences) with non-English text, and regrouped them on id. For some reason, whitespace was messing up the regrouping of the sentences.